# How do I implement a custom error function in a sklearn classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, loss-function

I want to treat errors from overestimates and underestimates differently (like The Price is Right) during model training. I don't want to rewrite the entire MLP, regression, DecisionTree, etc. algorithms in sklearn just to implement my custom cost function and relevant derivative. Is there a way for me to define a function any classifier can use to override the default? This is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
def myCustomError(y_preds,y_actuals):

    #Calculate The price is right style error

    return #not MSE


from sklearn import #Classifier


c = #Classifier(loss=myCustomError)
```

If I can't do this in sklearn but I have to use tensorflow or some other libraries, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where you'd need to define a custom loss function, a neural-net framework would typically be used rather than `sklearn`. One usually can't supply a custom optimisation function to `sklearn` algorithms. If you wanted to stick with `sklearn`, some algorithms allow you to configure sample importance or class balancing, but from your question it doesn't seem like the desired solution.

> I don't want to rewrite the entire MLP, regression, DecisionTree, etc.
> algorithms in sklearn just to implement my custom cost function and
> relevant derivative.

Not sure about decision trees, but MLPs and regression are straightforward to implement in PyTorch. Also, when you define a custom loss function, the derivative is taken care of for you. Here's a simple regression model using a custom loss function that penalises the overestimates more strongly than the underestimates:

Some mock data for this example (2D feature space, and target is a scalar):

```
#Test data
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
X0 = np.random.randn(128, 2) + 5
X1 = np.random.randn(128, 2)
X = np.concatenate([X0, X1], axis=0)
y = np.concatenate([np.linspace(0, 3, 128), np.linspace(-10, -5, 128)]).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Simple regression net with a custom loss function in PyTorch:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim

#Example of a custom loss function
#Treats overestimates differently to underestimates
def custom_loss(predictions, target):
        errors = predictions - target
        overestimates = errors[errors > 0]
        underestimates = errors[errors < 0]

        #penalise the square error of the overestimates more
        loss = (overestimates ** 2).sum() + (0.5 * underestimates ** 2).sum()
        return loss / len(target)

#Define a simple regression neural net
torch.manual_seed(0)
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(2, 4),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(4, 4),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(4, 1)
)

#Data to tensors
X_tensor = torch.tensor(X).to(torch.float32)
y_tensor = torch.tensor(y).to(torch.float32)

#Choose an optimiser and start training
optimiser = torch.optim.RMSprop(model.parameters())
n_epochs = 5

model.train()
for epoch in range(n_epochs):    
    predictions = model(X_tensor)
    loss = custom_loss(predictions, y_tensor)
    print('epoch', epoch, loss)
    
    #Backpropagation and optimisation step
    optimiser.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimiser.step()
```

For brevity this example leaves out details like scaling and batching the data (and keeping a validation set).